# Is the parent object reference changed if a child object is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have this

```
let a = { data: 'old' }
```

Lets say hypothetically that a has a reference to '123'

If I do

```
a.data = 'new'
```

Is the reference of a still pointing to '123' or has it been reallocated?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `'123'`? Your variable `a` has a reference to that object in your sample code. Changing a property of the object does not change the value of the variable `a`, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a very simple test for this:

```
let a = { data: "something" };
let b = a;
```

Now `a` and `b` are references to the exact same object.

```
a.data = "something else";
console.log(a === b); // true
```

Assigning to the property does not affect the value of `a`. Also:

```
console.log(b.data); // "something else"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetically, if `a` points to '123', you can assume that `a.data` points to '456'.

`a->123`

`a.data -> 456`

Now when you change `a.data` to "new" (say now at 789), you change the pointer for `a.data` so `a` would continue to point to the old value.

`a->123`

`a.data->789`

ReactJS specific: This is the reason why when dealing with object states, react may not re-render if you change a deep object key because the parent reference does not change.